# How to create magnifier on android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Hello everybody!
I'm trying to implement an magnifier.
It should make content under it looks bigger.

After some hours I have only one solution.

In my xml file, declare something like this (pseudo code):

```
<ZoomView>
    some other content views

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/magnifier
    />
</ZoomView>
```

In this code ZoomView is a custom view extends RelativeLayout. View with magnifier id is an actual magnifier that will zoom content.

This is how it looks like:

[image: magnifier]

So what happens in code.

In onDraw method of ZoomView I do this things.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    super.onDraw(bitmapCanvas);

    // some code that detects magnifier view position and size, 
    // than gets 1 area image, scale it to make in 2x bigger.
    // And then replace 2 area with this scaled image.

    // draw result on canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
}
```

This code works fine, but it is too slow. Can anyone give me an other solution or how can I optimize this one?

Sorry if something is wrong, this is my first question.

Comment: Amazing! No answers or comments and 5 minuses. Maybe someone will tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, there are 3 things wrong... **1.** Your question is very broad and has a lot of requirements (should work with everything, including text, and be movable, etc...). **2.** You haven't provided us with any thoughts or possibilities (so we don't know that you've at least attempted this yourself first). **3.** StackOverflow is not a place for asking a general question and getting people to write the code for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will change my post.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but I think performance could be improved by taking some of the processing out of the onDraw method. If the original size image/content is static you could easily create the magnified version of the content during onCreate (or better still, in an AsyncTask) and then when the magnifier is moved all you have to do is calculate what area of the content should be displayed of the magnified version, rather than trying to generate it every time.

If the content is dynamic instead you could still perform similar processing by having 2 constant copies of the content, one at normal size and one magnified and both are constantly kept up to date.

Your solution is otherwise on the right track. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to do this. I'll post result later.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if you need this, but some else might.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
Magnifier magnifier = new Magnifier(view);
magnifier.show(view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2);
```

if you want on user interaction then try this:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Fall through.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int[] viewPosition = new int[2];
                v.getLocationOnScreen(viewPosition);
                magnifier.show(event.getRawX() - viewPosition[0],
                               event.getRawY() - viewPosition[1]);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // Fall through.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                magnifier.dismiss();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
})
```

Using this magnifier you can magnify the view you want to.

FYI - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/magnifier