# Visual MAGNIFIER in Android possibilities

Tags: java, android

My final project is to make Visual magnifier in Android. It should work like Windows7 magnifier.I am searching for last many days regarding hints and guidance on Google but no help or idea. Can anyone have idea how to start work or it is possible?

Comment: Have you tried using Google? Because I did. And a lot of results appeared.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any search effort

Comment: If you are attempting to do this to magnify any app, that would require customizations at the OS level.

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417777/how-to-create-magnifier-on-android